# How to send variable from pinescrit strategy script to alert script

Tags: pine-script

i want to pass a variable from strategy script to the alert.

This is my actual situation :

I have a strategy script like this:

```
LongCondition = crossover(close,high[1])
if LongCondition
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Open")
```

and a study script to to execute it. All work good.

Now I need to set a variable for order quantity size, so i set a variable and :

```
mySize=8
LongCondition = crossover(close,high[1])
if LongCondition
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long,  comment="Open", qty=8)
```

Again, all work fine, the backtest work good.

Now i want to pass the mySize variable to the alert to execute it on Binance.
I use a external service for create an alert and put it on tradingviev create alert windows.
some like this:

```
{"pair":"BTCUSDT","units":"0.01","unitsType":"absolute","exchange":"blablabla","apiKey":"blablabla","token":"blablabla","isBuy":true,"isMarket":true}
```

But in this case i only can set a fixed "units" value, and always it will be the same, in the example i set "0.01" so always the order buy this size.

How can i pass to this script my variable "mySize" ?

I search and ask, the only solution (but don't work) is to copy the generated script
on my strategy.entry line. So the final code is

```
mySize=8
LongCondition = crossover(close,high[1])
if LongCondition
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long,  comment='{"pair":"BTCUSDT","units":"' + tostring(mySize) + '","unitsType":"absolute","exchange":"blablabla","apiKey":"blablabla","token":"blablabla","isBuy":true,"isMarket":true}')

But this do not work!

Can someone help me? thankyou
```

Answer (score 0):

first off its easiest to make a string variable, and use the variable in the call. We will call the variable key. Next its best to use it in the alert_message argument as to not have our key displaying on-chart.

```
key = ' {"pair":"BTCUSDT","units":"0.01","unitsType":"absolute","exchange":"blablabla","apiKey":"blablabla","token":"blablabla","isBuy":true,"isMarket":true} '

if LongCondition
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, alert_message=key)
```

Next you will need to make an alert. Within the alert message field you must delete all of the contents and place the following

```
{{strategy.order.alert_message}}
```

Then each time a long order is filled, this alert will be sent

Cheers, and all the best to you

Comment: thank you but don t work! alert send message but order on exchange don t exist...

Comment: you cant connect directly to binance this way

Comment: You need an intermediary to handle real http requests

Comment: Hello, yes i have it, actually i have script strategy, script sutdy where i create alert and tvhub bridge to send order in real time to exchange. My problem is that i only work with fixed size and this is not good risk managment strategy... i am able to calculate in my script the right contract quantity i only need to pass it at the createalert...